# Is speed of file opening/reading language dependent?

Tags: python, file, file-io, io, filesystems

I have really big collection of files, and my task is to open a couple of random files from this collection treat their content as a sets of integers and make an intersection of it.

This process is quite slow due to long times of reading files from disk into memory so I'm wondering whether this process of reading from file can be speed up by rewriting my program in some "quick" language. Currently I'm using python which could be inefficient for this kind of job.  (I could implement tests myself if I knew some other languages beside python and javascript...)

Also will putting all the date into database help? Files wont fit the RAM anyway so it will be reading from disk again only with database related overhead.

The content of files is the list of long integers. 90% of the files are quite small, less than a 10-20MB, but 10% left are around 100-200mb. As input a have filenames and I need read each of the files and output integers present in every file given. 
I've tried to put this data in mongodb but that was as slow as plain files based approach because I tried to use mongo index capabilities and mongo does not store indexes in RAM. 
Now I just cut the 10% of the biggest files and store rest in the redis, sometimes accessing those big files. This is, obviously temporary solution because my data grows and amount of RAM available does not.

Comment: Isn't the speed of doing _anything_ language-dependent?

Comment: Do you need to access *all* the data in these files, or just select pieces within the file? If the latter, maybe it could be faster to use ``mmap``. Also ``numpy`` might have something that could make in-memory storage of numbers (and calculating their intersections) more efficient. For disk storage, maybe consider using ``hdf5``? Can you describe in more detail what you've tried and provide more details of the nature of these files?

Comment: @MattBall I though all "modern" languages have advanced compilers/translators  which can effectively handle simple cases, so befenit of rewriting will be close to none if any.

Comment: @imm I need all the data as I need to intersect it with content of another files. I just see no other away around it

Comment: @Moonwalker, again, consider looking to converting your data to hdf5, so that you can access the arrays without having them have to be fully loaded into memory all at once. Have you tried this?

Comment: @imm, thanks for good idea, I will definitely try it.

Comment: @Moonwalker, also have a look at numpy.memmap and/or PyTables, which uses HDF. Or, consider working on chunks of the files at a time, calculating their intersections, and then moving on to the next chunks, and so on, and finally calculating the intersection of all the previously calculated intersections.

Comment: The reading of text files and converting their contents to some other data structure -- often containing that data in binary form -- will be relatively slow in any language. Would it be possible to at least store the integers in your data file in binary form?

Comment: @martineau There is no problem to store date in binary form, but why will it be faster? 
I think I should at least try to use pickle.

Comment: @Moonwalker: Binary data should be faster because it'll be a lot less bytes to read and the time spent converting strings of digit characters to internal binary form will be eliminated. Frankly I wouldn't expect `pickle` to be much better than pure text because it's still fundamentally a text-based format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try is calculating intersections of the files on a chunk-by-chunk basis (i.e., read x-bytes into memory from each, calculate their intersections, and continue, finally calculating the intersection of all intersections).

Or, you might consider using some "heavy-duty" libraries to help you. Consider looking into PyTables (with HDF storage)/using numpy for calculating intersections. The benefit there is that the HDF layer should help deal with not keeping the entire array structure in memory all at once---though I haven't tried any of these tools before, it seems like they offer what you need.

Comment: Can you sketch the code that does this chunk-by-chunk work? I don't immediately see how it can cope with the same integer appearing in different chunks in the two files. Also, did you mean "union of all intersections" rather than "intersection of all intersections"?

Answer (score 1):

If no file contains duplicate numbers, I'd try this:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -d
```

If they may contain duplicates, then you need to eliminate duplicates first:

```
sort -u file1 > /tmp/file1
sort -u file2 > /tmp/file2
cat /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 | sort | uniq -d
```

Or if you prefer a version that doesn't (explicitly) use temporary files.

```
(sort -u file1; sort -u file2) | sort | uniq -d
```

You don't say what format the files are in (the above assumes text, with one integer per line). If they're in some binary format, you would also need a command to translate them before applying the above commands. By using pipes you can compose this step like this:

```
(decode file1 | sort -u ; decode file2 | sort -u) | sort | uniq -d
```

Here `decode` is the name of a program you would have to write that parses your file format.

Apart from being incredibly short and simple, the good thing about this shell solution is that it works with files of any size, even if they don't fit into RAM.

It's not clear from your question whether you have 2 or an arbitrary number of files to intersect (the start of your question says "a couple", the end "a list of filenames"). To deal with, for example, 5 files instead of 2, use `uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1=="5") print $2; }'` instead of `uniq -d`

Comment: For reference, how `sort` can work with large files. http://vkundeti.blogspot.ch/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html